# Displaying Multiple rows with MySQL while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make it so that this code shows however many rows there are that match up with the owner. The owner that I'm using to test currently has three items but only one of the items shows up. How can I make it so that it displays all of the owner's items?

```
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $get = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE owner = '$username'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
    $check = mysql_num_rows($get);

    if($check == 0)
        echo "You have no items in your inventory.";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
    {
        echo "<p>Item Name:" . $row['name'] . "</p></br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're fetching the first row and then doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $get = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE owner = '$username'");
    // deleted
    $check = mysql_num_rows($get);

    if($check == 0)
        echo "You have no items in your inventory.";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
    {
        echo "<p>Item Name:" . $row['name'] . "</p></br>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `mysql_fetch_assoc` right after `@mysql_query`. It already fetches one record there and moves the internal data poiner ahead.

On a side note: you should use proper escaping of username, because in that form the code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the first `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);`.